# TypeError: an integer is required in python mysql

Tags: mysql-python

I want to simply access the database of mysql through python.But when I am running this code :

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1",
                     port = "3306",
                      user="Bishnu",
                      passwd = "Pulchowk",
                      db = "student")
cursor =db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from basic_info")
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    print row[0],"-->",row[1]
db.cose()
```

It gives an error as :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bishnu\Desktop\database", line 6, in <module>
    db = "student")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What is that 
TypeError : an integer is required

Why such problem occurs?
To run this code I have got 3 problems but luckily this forum solved my two problems, I think it will also be solved ?

Comment: it may not be able to connect to the mysql server. Make sure its running.

Comment: I am sure that Mysql server is running, but it still shows the same problem. But my friend also have tried it but he has no problem. Any ohter idea about it ?

Answer (score 16):

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1",
                 port = "3306",
                  user="Bishnu",
                  passwd = "Pulchowk",
                  db = "student")
```

try replacing:

```
port = "3306"
```

with

```
port = 3306
```

(remove the quotes)

Comment: I have tried but shows the error             OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'Bishnu'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Comment: That means the IntegerType error is solved, however now it's a credential problem.  double-check your credentials to log into mysql, perhaps double check via command-line.

Comment: furthermore - it's in your best interest to _REMOVE_ any passwords before posting on public boards.